# Deploying to ArcGIS 10 Server .NET/Java

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-server

We're in the process of transforming a lot of 9.1 ArcServer/ArcObjects etc applications to ArcGIS Server 10.

However, we're unsure as to licensing on 10.

As I understand it, I cannot, according to license restrictions, deploy a toolbox that has been written using ArcObjects 10 .NET SDK on the ArcGIS 10 Server for Java platform, for licensing issues.  We *can* deploy a .NET application to an ArcGIS Java Server 10 instance, if we bundle up all of the application object references in the installer, but this goes against the license agreements (you're not allowed to bundle them up in the installer apparently), so these have to be deployed on an ArcGIS 10 .NET Server instance.  Is that pretty much the long and the short of it?

I am sure we can't have two different flavour instances of ArcGIS 10 Server installed on the same machine (one Java, one .NET) so they need to be on separate boxes (or VM's)?

Thanks in advance for any words of calm...

Comment: I am tempted to answer this, but for legal reasons, I would recommend you ask your Esri account manager for the final word.  (But then post the outcome here)

Comment: OK, what are the legal reasons?  The app has been deployed that way in production for years!  But it is best practises now, which mean we want to ensure we're all up to licensing regulations.

Comment: Still nothing back, I can actually see how you can have both on one box, each pointing to a different set of arcgis 'system' folders, but that looks way not the way to do things for us.  I am also assured we'd still need 2 licenses, one for each sdk...

Comment: The come back is that they don't know, that it's an unusual question.  In my experience with ESRIUK, this actually means they don't know, they've passed a question to Redlands, and are waiting for their reply.  The man I am dealing with was absolutely on the money with ArcSDE migration, and licensing, so I have no beef with them, they are trying their hardest, but sometimes they simply don't have all the answers, which I understand.  I'll keep it updated, but I can't be the first to have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared wrappers for ArcObjects, which are language specific, are only installed with the relevant version of AGS  i.e. ArcGIS Server .Net uses the .Net version wrappers for AO and so can run .Net AO apps and tools, the only way to install these .Net wrappers for the Java version would be to create a custom install of them with the application and it is this which would break the licensing conditions.

It is possible to install AGS Java and .Net side by side on the same machine theoretically.  However, that configuration is not formally supported and it isn’t straight forward. ESRI advise against it. The approved way to make the two different versions talk to each other is through their Web Services (SOAP and REST). This would probably be through separate VMs.  This may be slightly more costly up front but will be supportable and without doubt cost less in the longer term.

So, as thought, it's possible, but not supported